# can I prove my hypothesis using t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference

I am doing EDA on my customer transaction data. The dataframe looks like this.

[image]

I have close to 5000+ customer, who has done transaction with a set of 112 vendors only.When I did the EDA I found almost 95% of the customer has done transaction with 1 vendors only.

In the above sample record, If you see I have a customer(ID) 1 has done transaction with only Apply and a another record with Vendor_Group as "UNKNOWN".If you see almost all the records has the 95% customer data look like this only.And for others They have done transaction with 2 vendors.

As @BruceET mention in the comment, the main issue is vendor reported vs. Unknown?

I have this hypothesis, that the "**Unkown**" in the Vendor_group variable is because of the data has not been captured. And the customer has not done transaction with other vendor.

Can I prove this hypothesis using t-test?

Comment: Just a comment on terminology: You can't "prove" anything with a statistical test.  You might come to a conclusion, but it doesn't "prove" the hypothesis.

Comment: Do you have data on only three customers or is this just a bit of info to show how a larger dataframe looks? Only three specific Vendors appear (Apple, Lenovo, Microsoft); how many in all? A dozen or a hundred? Is vendor reported vs. Unknown the main issue? Or are you also interested in _which_ vendors are used and whether some are more likely to be reported? // Just from what you show, I don't see a direct path towards identifying or explaining poor data capture or customer behavior. Can you explain what your purpose is and why you think such data will help your toward it?

Comment: Yes,vendor reported vs. Unknown is the main issue

Answer (score 0):

No. In fact, as it reads now, this is not even a statistical hypothesis.

Why some results are "unknown" relates to how the data was collected. To figure it out, you would have to look at that process.

However, in your edits and comments you suggest that you might actually be interested in something else, namely, whether sales are different with known vs. unknown vendors. This *might* be answerable with  a t-test. You would have to recode group into "known" and "unknown" and then do the t-test. But sales data often is very skew, so some other test might be better, depending on the nature of your data and what exactly you are trying to find out.